# Finding the position of a number in a list

Tags: recursion, scheme

Hey guys, I have a homework question that's been frustrating me to no end! I'm supposed to create index-of-least that will take a non-empty list and return the index of the smallest number in the list. The index of the (car ls) = 0, index of the (car (cdr ls)) = 1, and so on.

A helper needs to be created that will keep track of the current-position, least-position, least-value, and list. So far,  I have this program (that doesn't load) that shows the basic algorithm.. But I'm having a hard time keeping track of everything and putting it into chez scheme code.

```
(define index-helper
  (lambda (ls current-position least-position least-value)
    (if (> (car ls) least-value)
        (add1 (car ls (cdr ls (add1 current-position))))
        (car ls (cdr ls (add1 current-position))))))

;trace
;ls: (4231) c-pos: 0 least-value: 5 least-pos: 0
;ls: (231) c-pos: 1 least-value: 4 least-pos: 1
;ls: (31) c-pos 2 least-value: 2 least-pos: 2
;ls: 1 c-pos: 3 l-v: 2 l-pos: 2
;ls '() c-pos: 4 l-v: 1 l-pos: 4
;*least-position = current-position
```

I already googled this and found similar questions in python, but I don't understand the code because I'm new to programming. :P 
If anyone can give me a hint, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: How about asking in #scheme instead? I don't think the instructors want their homework problems to show up on Google like this.

Comment: @erjiang: Aren't IRC convos logged, too? ;-)

Comment: @Yasir: Haha, yeah, but SO has been SEO'd so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two functions. The first function find the least element `x`. The second function finds the index of the element `x` in the list.

Something like:

```
(define (find-least xs)
  (foldl (lambda (e acc) (min e acc)) (car xs) xs))

(define (elem-index x xs)
  (define (elem-index-find x xs ind)
    (cond
      ((empty? xs) ind)
      ((eq? x (car xs))
       ind)
      (else (elem-index-find x (cdr xs) (+ ind 1)))))
  (if (empty? xs)
      (error "empty list")
      (elem-index-find x xs 0)))

(define (index-of-least xs)
  (let ((least (find-least xs)))
    (elem-index least xs)))
```

Test:

```
> (index-of-least (list 5 8 4 9 1 3 7 2))
4
```

Or, in one pass:

```
(define (index-of-least-1-pass xs)
  (define (index-do least ind-least ind xs)
    (cond
      ((empty? xs) ind-least)
      ((< (car xs) least)
       (index-do (car xs) (+ ind 1) (+ ind 1) (cdr xs)))
      (else
       (index-do least ind-least (+ ind 1) (cdr xs)))))
  (index-do (car xs) 0 0 (cdr xs)))
```

Test:

```
> (index-of-least-1-pass (list 5 8 4 9 1 3 7 2))
4
```

In `index-do` helper function first you check if the intermediate list is empty; this is a base case, when we have got just one element int the list, and return its index.

Next condition checks if the next element of the intermediate list is greater than the current `least` value, and if so, we call helper with the new value of `least` and its index.

The last condition is selected, when the next element is not greater than the `least`, and it calls the helper function with the same values of `least` and `ind-least`, and the intermediate list with head element removed until there are no elements in the list, and we approached the base case, when there are no elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

A good example for *named let*:

```
(define (index-of-least xs)
  (let loop ((i 0) (p 0) (x (car xs)) (xs (cdr xs)))
    (cond ((null? xs) p)
          ((< (car xs) x) (loop (+ i 1) (+ i 1) (car xs) (cdr xs)))
          (else (loop (+ i 1) p x (cdr xs))))))

(index-of-least (list 5 8 4 9 1 3 7 2)) => 4
```